# Command-line arguments for Kotlin program

Tags: kotlin, encryption, command-line, arguments

I stuck with a project. It's an encryption-decryption program. But to complicate the things it uses command-line arguments instead of user input. I solved the user input part. But this part is really hard for me. Here is the objective:

Objectives
The program must parse three arguments: -mode, -key, and -data. The first argument should determine the program's mode (enc for encryption, dec for decryption). The second argument is an integer key to modify the message, and the third is a text or ciphertext to encrypt/decrypt.

Arguments are guaranteed to be passed to the program. If, for some reason, they turn out to be wrong:

If there is no -mode, the program should work in the enc mode;
If there is no -key, the program should consider that it is 0;
If there is no -data, the program should assume that data is an empty string.
Keep in mind that the order of the arguments might be different. For example, -mode enc maybe at the end, at the beginning, or in the middle of the array.

Examples
Example 1: encryption; the arguments are: -mode enc -key 5 -data "Welcome to hyperskill!"

\jqhtrj%yt%m~ujwxpnqq&

java -jar programName.jar -mode enc -key 5 -data "Welcome to hyperskill!"
This way the program inputs \jqhtrj%yt%m~ujwxpnqq&
But how to achieve the same input if the program starts with for example
java -jar programName.jar -data "Welcome to hyperskill!" -mode enc -key 5 ?? The encoding-decoding part is done in the previous stage.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a programming exercise, or will it be used in production? (If the latter, it might be both easier and more maintainable to use a library for parse command-line arguments, rather than doing it yoursef.)

Comment: Programming exercise!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the command line arguments will always come in the format of `-nameOfArgument` and then immediately followed by the argument itself, here is a simple way. For more complicated command line options, I would recommend using a parser library like [kotlinx-cli](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-cli).

Because of the assumption, you will always find an even number of elements in the arguments array passed to `main`. You can make this array [`chunked`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) into lists of 2 elements each, and then [`associate`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/associate.html) the two elements into a `Map`.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val argsMap = args.toList().chunked(2).associate { it[0] to it[1] }
}
```

After that, `argsMap["-mode"]` gets you the mode, `argsMap["-key"]` gets you the key. These could also be null, which means that that argument is not passed.

Comment: Still not understand how to call these arguments. For example if the user want to encrypt Welcome to hyperskill with a key 5. The encryption part is like:
for (char in ??argsMap) {
print(char + ??argsMap)
} The double question mark stands for what need to be written there! With simple user input I can make it to work, but with command-line arguments is a little bit hard to.

Comment: @TiborTóth You would do `for (char in argsMap["-data"] ?: "")`. You use `argsMap["-data"]` to access the data argument. And note that since the arguments can be absent, `?:` is used to specify a default value to use when it is absent - in this case, an empty string for `-data`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly thanks to Sweeper for the assistance! Maybe not the finest solution, but here is my code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val argsMap = args.toList().chunked(2).associate { it[0] to it[1] }

    if (argsMap["-mode"] == "enc" || argsMap["-mode"] == "") {
            for (char in argsMap["-data"] ?: "") {
                    print(char + (argsMap["-key"]?.toInt() ?: "".toInt()))
            }
    } else if (argsMap["-mode"] == "dec") {
            for (char in argsMap["-data"] ?: "") {
                    print(char - (argsMap["-key"]?.toInt() ?: "".toInt()))
            }
    } else if (argsMap["-key"] == "") {
            print(argsMap["-data"])
    } else if (argsMap["-data"] == "") {
            print("")
    }
```

}